# Trouble positioning an element inside a container

Tags: html, css

Here's a JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/5NzYm/1/

I'm trying to position the Blog element in the top left corner of the third container. But it's position is in the top left of the page.

```
<home class="grid_block">2</home>
    <home class="grid_block">3</home>
    <home class="grid_block">
        <block class="update_type">Blog</block>
</home>

home.grid_block {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 224px;
    width: 23.35%;
    margin: 0 2.2% 2.2% 0;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
block.update_type {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 50;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #313131;
}
```

Comment: try position relative

`block.update_type {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 50;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #313131;
}`

Comment: Thanks, that was a stupid omission on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy fix. Just add `position:relative` to `home.grid_block`

```
home.grid_block {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 224px;
    width: 23.35%;
    margin: 0 2.2% 2.2% 0;
    background-color: #CCC;
    position:relative;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5NzYm/2/)**

An absolutely positioned element is positioned with respect to its closest positioned ancestor. You just needed to make that ancestor the .grid_block.

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:relative;` to container:

```
home.grid_block {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 224px;
    width: 23.35%;
    margin: 0 2.2% 2.2% 0;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a style of `position: relative` on the `home.grid-block` selector. Position relative is required for a parent container to have any absolutely positioned children.